# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FormatTypes')

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

I am using ethers v6 and am trying to update the frontend files for the abi.json and a json file for the contract address. The contract address is being filled correctly but the abi.json file is not. Currently the abi file looks like this -

```
{
    
}
```

Here is the script that I am using to format the abi.json file-

```
import { useWeb3Contract } from "react-moralis"
import { abi, contractAddress } from "../constants"
import { useMoralis } from "react-moralis"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { ethers } from "ethers"
import { useNotification } from "web3uikit"

export default function LotteryEntrance() {
    const { chainId: chainIdHex, isWeb3Enabled } = useMoralis()
    const chainId = parseInt(chainIdHex)
    const raffleAddress = chainId in contractAddress ? contractAddress[chainId][0] : null
    const [entranceFee, setEntranceFee] = useState("0")
    const [numPlayers, setNumPlayers] = useState("0")
    const [recentWinner, setRecentWinner] = useState("0")



    const dispatch = useNotification()

    const { runContractFunction: enterRaffle } = useWeb3Contract({
        abi: abi,
        contractAddress: contractAddress,
        functionName: "enterRaffle",
        params: {},
        msgValue: entranceFee,
    })

    const { runContractFunction: getEntraceFee } = useWeb3Contract({
        abi: abi,
        contractAddress: raffleAddress,
        functionName: "getEntraceFee",
        params: {},
    })

    const { runContractFunction: getNumberOfPlayers } = useWeb3Contract({
        abi: abi,
        contractAddress: raffleAddress,
        functionName: "getNumberofPlayers",
        params: {},
    })

    const { runContractFunction: getRecentWinner } = useWeb3Contract({
        abi: abi,
        contractAddress: raffleAddress,
        functionName: "getRecentWinner",
        params: {},
    })

    async function updateUI() {
        const entranceFeeFromCall = (await getEntraceFee()).toString()
        const numPlayersFromCall = (await getNumberOfPlayers()).toString()
        const recentWinnerFromCall = await getRecentWinner()
        setEntranceFee(entranceFeeFromCall)
        setNumPlayers(numPlayersFromCall)
        setRecentWinner(recentWinnerFromCall)
        console.log(entranceFee)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isWeb3Enabled) {
            updateUI()
        }
    }, [isWeb3Enabled])

    const handleSuccess = async function (tx) {
        await tx.wait(1)
        handleNewNotification(tx)
        updateUI()
    }

    const handleNewNotification = function () {
        dispatch({
            type: "info",
            message: "Transaction Complete",
            title: "Tx Notification",
            position: "topR",
            icon: "bell",
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            Hi from lottery entrance!
            {raffleAddress ? (
                <div>
                    <button
                        onClick={async function () {
                            await enterRaffle({
                                onSuccess: handleSuccess,
                                onError: (error) => console.log(error),
                            })
                        }}
                    >
                        Enter Raffle
                    </button>
                    Entrance Fee {ethers.utils.formatUnits(entranceFee, "ether")} ETH
                    Number Of Players: {numPlayers} 
                    Recent Winner: {recentWinner}
                </div>
            ) : (
                <div>No Raffle Address Detected.</div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```